# chat application in android so that sender and receiver message should be on different side

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, message

```
 protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> myArrayList)//    for arraylist(ArrayList<String> result)
   {                            

       for (HashMap<String, String> data : myArrayList)
      {
           String sender_no = data.get(TAG_SENDER_NO);
           String msg1=data.get(TAG_SEN_MSG);
           String receiver_no=data.get(TAG_RECEIVER_NO);

           if(sender_no.equals(senderno))
           {

           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SinglechatActivity.this, myArrayList,R.layout.list_row_layout_even, 
           new String[] { TAG_SEN_MSG },new int[] { R.id.message_me });

        //  CustomList adapter= new CustomList(SinglechatActivity.this,myArrayList);//sender_no,  msg1,   receiver_no);

         ListView  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
           lv.setAdapter( adapter);

          }

           else

           {
               ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SinglechatActivity.this, myArrayList,R.layout.list_row_layout_odd, 
                       new String[] { TAG_SEN_MSG },new int[] { R.id.message_frnd });

                //  CustomList adapter= new CustomList(SinglechatActivity.this,  sender_no,  msg1,   receiver_no);

                 ListView  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
                   lv.setAdapter( adapter);

           }
```

In this, I would like to have message on right hand side and left hand side based on the sender and receiver.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Custom adapter` with separate layouts for sender and receiver messages. It is called `Heterogeneous ListView`.

Something like this

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> messages;
    int SENDER_MESSAGE = 0;
    int RECEIVER_MESSAGE = 1;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return messages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        //This is dummy logic
        //Write your own logic to differentiate between sender and receiver message
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            return SENDER_MESSAGE;
        }

        else {
            return RECEIVER_MESSAGE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (getItemViewType(position) == SENDER_MESSAGE) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sender_message_layout, null);
            } 

            else {
                //Received message
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.received_message_layout, null);
            }
        }

            //...set text to message layout here


    }



}
```

For more info on `Custom Adapter` you can refer this

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example

For heterogeneous ListView (Different row layouts in ListView) tutorial you can refer this

http://chrislee.kr/wp/tag/getitemviewtype-tutorial/

Comment: abhishek i have tried this but i didn't get ....could you plz help me out of this

Comment: can you please update the question with the latest code you have tried?

Comment: Can't you post it here itself? Edit your question and add your latest code

Comment: you need to have emoticon parser , are you doing that? post the code , what problem are you facing?

Comment: @amit Have a look at this sample app https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard

Comment: user595169  how to do dat ??

Answer (score 0):

In your onBindViewHolder() method of your recyclerView adapter you can align the sender or receiver view layout programatically using an "if" statement. For example if it is sender align left or right, e.t.c. Use the code below for example to access and set the view layout parameters:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
 (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);
 button.setLayoutParams(params);
```