# ListView (activity feed) with 20 different types of rows, each having 20 different views

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

A week ago I asked a question on stackoverflow about having a listview with different kinds of items in it.

[I know how to populate a list with custom items via custom adapter. But how do I populate it with a few different types of items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825536/i-know-how-to-populate-a-list-with-custom-items-via-custom-adapter-but-how-do-i)

At the time I didnt know that it would have made a difference so I mentioned I only have 4 types of list items not to complicate things. I got some responses with extremely simple cases explained (2 types of items with a single view inside each one). I dont think I can implement those approaches explained in the examples I got, I need a more object oriented approach.

I would like to have a separate class that takes an XML layout and deals with its views and its buttons.

Something like this:

```
public class MyProfileCommentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> itemNames =  new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Double> itemRatings = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private ArrayList<String> itemComments  = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> itemCommentDates   = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> itemIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private ImageButton iMyCommentsCommentedProductImage;
    private TextView tvMyCommentsCommentedItemName;
    private TextView tvMyCommentsCommentedItemDate;
    private TextView tvMyCommentsCommentedItemContent;
    private TextView tvMyCommentsCommentedItemRating;
    private Button bMyCommentsEditComment;
    private Button bMyCommentsDeleteComment;

    public MyProfileCommentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> itemNames, ArrayList<Double> itemRatings, ArrayList<String> itemComments, ArrayList<String> itemCommentDates, ArrayList<Integer> itemIds){

        this.context = context;
        this.itemNames = itemNames;
        this.itemComments = itemComments;
        this.itemCommentDates = itemCommentDates;
        this.itemRatings = itemRatings;
        this.itemIds = itemIds;

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemIds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return itemIds.get(arg0)    ;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return itemIds.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_adapterable_my_profile_comment, parent, false);
        }

        iMyCommentsCommentedProductImage = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iMyCommentsCommentedProductImage);
        tvMyCommentsCommentedItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyCommentsCommentedItemName);
        tvMyCommentsCommentedItemDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyCommentsCommentedItemDate);
        tvMyCommentsCommentedItemContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyCommentsCommentedItemContent);
        tvMyCommentsCommentedItemRating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyCommentsCommentedItemRating);
        bMyCommentsEditComment = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bMyCommentsEditComment);
        bMyCommentsDeleteComment = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bMyCommentsDeleteComment);    

        tvMyCommentsCommentedItemName.setText(itemNames.get(position));
        tvMyCommentsCommentedItemDate.setText(itemCommentDates.get(position));
        tvMyCommentsCommentedItemRating.setText(String.valueOf(itemRatings.get(position)));
        tvMyCommentsCommentedItemContent.setText(itemComments.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I need to have about 20 of these and put them all in a list view (the activity feed of my app), depending on what activities have recently occurred in my app. Each different activity has a separate XML defined with as much view elements in it, as this one, all doing and displaying different stuff.

Now, If I was to use the suggested approach,

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.separator, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }
```

Looks simple, doesnt it?
But in my case, I should have 20 different cases in the SWITCH and each one should have 20-30 rows of code in it. I dont want to implement it this way. Sadly, I have no clue of what to do...

Comment: http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Comment: NICE!!!!!!! If you provide that as an answer I'd accept it. the first link is exactly what Im looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following link, hope it helps in resolving your issue: 
[Magic Happens here](http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/)